# How to use $(this) in functions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<select id="sel">
    <option id="1">aa</option>
    <option id="2">bb</option>
    <option id="3">cc</option>
</select>

<select id="two">
    <option id="1">aa</option>
    <option id="2">bb</option>
    <option id="3">cc</option>
</select>


function showalert(){
  alert($(this).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert();
});

$("#two").change(function(){
   showalert();
});
```

How to correctly use `$(this)` in these function? Now `this` is `undefined.`

Comment: I'm a little dismayed to see how many seasoned JS answerers are re-using the OP's `$(this).find('option:selected').attr('id')` instead of properly using the DOM, as in [Alnitak's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8809730), `this.options[this.selectedIndex].id`.  The latter is shorter, faster and better in every single way.

Comment: @AndyE it's worse than that - the OP was shown how to correctly access the ID in a previous question and _still_ used that method.

Comment: @Alnitak: wow. I think the OP can still be excused because he wasn't told in any of the answers why the plain DOM version is better (faster, shorter).  But it's still disappointing to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pass `$(this)` to the function.

```
function showalert(that){
  alert(that.find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert($(this));
});

$("#two").change(function(){
   showalert($(this));
});
```

---

Edited from the comments.

The comments are suggesting that you do not pass a jQuery object and infact it makes sense as it is just extra code and should be refactored into the method.

```
function showalert(that){
  alert($(that).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert(this);
});

$("#two").change(function(){
   showalert(this);
});
```

Comment: you shouldn't wrap elements up into jQuery objects until you have to.  And once you get that far you might well find a native DOM method or property that's more efficient.

Comment: so _now_ you can use `that.option[that.selectedIndex].id` - see - no jQuery object or methods! ;-)

Answer (score 10):

You just need to rewrite your two `.change` calls thus:

```
$("#sel").change(showalert);
$("#two").change(showalert);
```

There's no need to "wrap" a call to `showalert` inside another function - it's already a reference to a function and jQuery will ensure that `this` is set to the target element.

FWIW, the two selectors can even be combined, as they have the same handler:

```
$("#sel,#two").change(showalert);
```

Furthermore, you shouldn't use `id` like that on your `<option>` tags.  `id` tags are supposed to be unique across the entire document, and until HTML5 weren't even allowed to be numbers.

It should be the `value` attribute instead, or if you're already using that for something else, a `data-xxx` attribute.

Leaving it as an `id` for now, your handler then just becomes

```
function showalert() {
    alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].id);
}
```

Working demo based on using `value` at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/54Pd9/

Comment: @Esailija you should undelete your answer, at least it was correct!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer. It's a no-brainer, really.

Answer (score 4):

`this` is set based on how you call the function

You should just pass the `this` element as an ordinary parameter:

```
function showalert(elem) {
  alert($(elem).find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert(this);
});
```

Comment: _"You should just pass the this element as an ordinary parameter:"_ - I disagree - the handler itself should just be registered directly, at which point its parameter is the whole event and `this` is the target element.

Comment: @Alnitak: Nah. He's got a nice jQuery-driven API function now.

Answer (score 3):

pass it as parameter like

```
function test(elem) {
  $(elem).text();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have use [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to call `showalert` with `this` as the [function context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context).

```
showalert.call(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function showalert(elem){
  alert(elem.find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert($(this));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :** add reference to jquery library in the head of the page.

**Step 2 :** write this inside a script tag in the head :

```
$(function(){

$("#sel").change(function(){
   showalert($(this));
});

$("#two").change(function(){
   showalert($(this));
});

})
function showalert(x){
  alert(x.find('option:selected').attr('id'));
}
```

Comment: That will not work, `this` at that point isn't the element that changed.

Comment: I was referencing your original code, before the edit. After the edit, it will work.

Comment: you've double wrapped your `this` object - you've effectively now got `$($(this))`