# How to use $(this) in jquery functions?

Tags: jquery, function, this

I'm trying to get this function work – but it didn't get the geht the $(this) if it's fired. I found this question what seems to be really similar question ([How to use $(this) in functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809691/how-to-use-this-in-functions)) but i cant figure out why it isnt working in my case.

It would be great if someone can help me. Thanks

```js
    function scrolll(){
        var thiss = $(this).attr('id').substring(1);
        var pos = $(this).scrollTop();
        // var next = Number(thiss) + 1;
        // var prev = Number(thiss) - 1;

        count = Number(thiss);

        if (pos == 0) {
            $(".section#s" + (count - 1)).removeClass( "inactive", 1500, "linear" );
            $(this).removeClass( "active", 1500, "linear" );
            var count = Number(thiss) - 1;
        }

        if($(this).scrollTop() + $(this).innerHeight() >= $(this)[0].scrollHeight) {
            $(this).addClass( "inactive", 1500, "linear" );
            $(".section#s" + (count + 1)).addClass( "active", 1500, "linear" ); 
            var count = Number(thiss) + 1; 
            console.log("countbefore: " + count);
            count++;
            console.log("countafter: " + count);
        }
    }




$('.section1').on('scroll', function() {
        console.log(thiss)
        scrolll($(this));
    });

$('.section2').on('scroll', function() {
        console.log(thiss)
        scrolll($(this));
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest option is to add a parameter to `scrolll` and not worry abut it, eg:

```
function scrolll(el)
{
    var $this = $(el)
    var thiss = $this.attr('id').substring(1);

    .... etc

$('.section2').on('scroll', function() {
    scrolll(this);
});
```

---

But what you are looking for is `call`:

```
function scrolll()
{
    ....

$('.section2').on('scroll', function() {
    scrolll.call(this);
});
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that was exactly what i was looking for. – and it work.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` is primarily used in a function relating to the selector.

E.g.

```
$('.button').click(function(){
$(this).css('color','red');
});
```

In this case, $(this) would target the `.button` selector.

Comment: That's exactly the scenario it's being used in, but wanting to pass it on to a common function.